# Excel Macro Autofilter issue with variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of data with the top row being filters, I have a loop that changes which filter needs to be used inside the loop is the variable filterColumn that is being assigned a new value every time the loop runs through.

when i try to use filterColumn to determine which filter will be 'switched on' i get an error

> Autofilter method of Range Class Failed

`ActiveSheet.Range("$U$83:$CV$1217").AutoFilter Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:="<>"`

What is the correct syntax in order to use a variable to determine which field the filter is in?

**Problem Solved** I found the solution. I was referencing the filters columns position in terms of the whole worksheet when in fact I should have been referencing what number it was in the group of filters. For example the filter I wanted to change was in 'CF' which is the 84th column but my the filter I wanted to change is the 64th in the group.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim filterColumn As Integer
filterColumn = 2
ActiveSheet.Range("$U$83:$CV$1217").AutoFilter Field:=filterColumn, _
    Criteria1:="<>"
```

Comment: I tried that, I originally had 'Dim filterColumn as int' but it still doesn't work either way

Comment: Yes, if i change Field:=filterColumn to Field:=64 it works for the filter in the 64th column. So the issue is purely with Field:=filterColumn

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? The snippet I posted works in my workbook with either the variable or with a number hard-coded into the field argument. There must be something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I tried @HeadofCatering's solution and initially it failed. However I filled in values in the referenced columns and it worked (my solution also failed under reverse conditions - make the column headers blank and it fails).

However this doesn't quite mesh with what I've (and probably you've) seen - you can definitely add filters to columns with blank headers. However one thing was consistent in the failures I saw - the `filterColumn` referenced a column that was outside of `Application.UsedRange`. You may want to try verifying that the column you are referencing is actually within `Application.UsedRange` (easy way: run `Application.UsedRange.Select` in the Immediate Window and see if your column is selected). Since you are referencing a decent amount of columns, it is possible that there are no values past a certain point (including column headers), and when you specify the column to filter, you are actually specifying something outside of your `UsedRange`.

An interesting (this is new to me as well) thing to test is taking a blank sheet, filling in values in cells `A1` and `B1`, selecting columns `A:G` and manually adding AutoFilters - this will only add filters to columns A and B (a related situation can be found if you try to add filters to a completely blank sheet).

Sorry for the babble - chances are this isn't even your problem :)

---

**Old solution (doesn't work when conditions described above are used)**

I may be overkilling it, but try setting the sheet values as well (note I used a sample range here):

```
Sub SOTest()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filterColumn As Integer

' Set the sheet object and declare your variable
Set ws = ActiveSheet
filterColumn = 2

' Now try the filter
ws.Range("$A$1:$E$10").AutoFilter Field:=filterColumn, Criteria1:="<>"

End Sub
```

Comment: OP says that the autofilter works if he hard-codes a 64 in place of the variable. Referencing the worksheet isn't the issue.

Comment: @HeadofCatering Yeah, I edited my answer (and left the old/incorrect one in there for posterity's sake :) ) - my best guess is the whole `Application.UsedRange` issue mentioned above, but it is just like you say - there must be something else going on.

Comment: Dont' think usedrange is the issue either. If hard-coding 64 works, so would passing an integer variable with a value of 64.

Comment: Do you think it could be because he is wrapping it in a loop? My thought was that some parts of the loop (may) work, but it fails once the column increases outside of the range. Also, do you think maybe it has something to do with setting the AutoFilter at the sheet level?

Comment: It's probably something like that. We need to see the rest of his code.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I tried the `Application.UsedRange.Select` it didn't work but `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select` worked, my filters and all the data included in them were selected so that's not the issue. I don't know if this will help but the filters already exist on the page before i run the macro, all the macro does is tell the filter what data to filter out.

Comment: @AndrewConnelly Hmm, it is a bit tough to pin down since testing it would require quite a bit of setup. Can you see if `filterColumn` is defined at the time it is executed? Try turning on the `Locals` view and see if filterColumn still contains a value at the time it will be executed (this is me doing some 'grasping-at-straws' action :) ). Also, does it fail on the first or second execution?